# What are the equations of rotated and shifted ellipse, parabola and hyperbola in the general conic sections form?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections, elliptic-equations, hyperbolic-equations

How will look the general conic sections equation $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ in case of rotated and shifted from coordinates origin ellipse, parabola and hyperbola?

I need a formulas for coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ for ellipse, hyperbola and parabola. I did it for not-rotated conic sections at the origin of coordinates but have a difficults with rotated and shifted.

For i.e. standart ellipse equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ gives me general equation $\frac{1}{a^2}x^2 + 0xy + \frac{1}{b^2}y^2 + 0x + 0y - 1 = 0$

I need the same in case if ellipse located in position $(h;k)$ and rotated on some angle $\alpha$ from positive $X$ axis. And the same for parabola and hyperbola.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking. They all look like your general conic section. The exact values of the coefficients will give you the shape, the rotation, and the translation from the origin.

Comment: I need a formulas for coefficients A, B, C, D, E and F for ellipse, hyperbola and parabola. I did it for not-rotated conic sections at the origin of coordinates but have a difficults with rotated and shifted

Comment: All the qualitative information comes with  taking the Hessian matrix $H$ of your quadratic polynomial  and constructing a nonsingular matrix $P$  such that $P^T H P = M$  is diagonal. $$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2A&B&D \\
B&2C&E \\
D&E&2F \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: The matrix $P$  need not be orthogonal, you do not need the eigenvalues of $H$  see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: @WillJagy I didn't understand anything from your commentary. It's too advanced math for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to derive these formulas. Let's take the case of the ellipse. Originally you have $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
If you rotate the coordinate system by an angle $\theta$, you get $$x\to x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\y\to x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$$
So the equation becomes $$\frac{(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)^2}{b^2}=1$$
If you translate the origin by $(x_0,y_0)$, the equation above transforms to $$\frac{(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta+x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta+y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$$
Now all you need to do is to expand the parentheses, and group the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Expand $$(\frac{(x-h)\cos(\alpha)+(y-k)\sin(\alpha)}{a})^2+(\frac{-(x-h)\sin(\alpha)+(y-k)\cos(\alpha)}{b})^2-1=0$$ to get the ellipses. The general equation $$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$ might give you an empty conic e.g. expand $$(\frac{(x-h)\cos(\alpha)+(y-k)\sin(\alpha)}{a})^2+(\frac{-(x-h)\sin(\alpha)+(y-k)\cos(\alpha)}{b})^2+1=0.$$  The hyperbolas come from expanding  $$(\frac{(x-h)\cos(\alpha)+(y-k)\sin(\alpha)}{a})^2-(\frac{-(x-h)\sin(\alpha)+(y-k)\cos(\alpha)}{b})^2-1=0.$$ The parabolas come from expanding $$2p(-(x-h)\sin(\alpha)+(y-k)\cos(\alpha))= ((x-h)\cos(\alpha)+(y-k)\sin(\alpha))^2,$$ where $p$ is the semi-latus rectum.

And all equations can of course be multiplied by a constant without changing anything.